# How do I express 'a square' with a specific length of its side?

Tags: prepositions, articles

How do I put articles and prepositions into the following expression, please?

> A square with [**a/the/nothing**] side [**of/with**] [**a/the/nothing**] length [**of/nothing**] 42

In my native language (Slovak) it is common to use the genitive case in such situations, that's why "of" seems fine to me there.

What are the correct options here, please?

Comment: A square with a side with a length of 42.

Comment: Perhaps personal taste, but I would not use "with a" twice. A square with a side of length ... or a 42 centimetre square.

Comment: You can also say "A square with a 42 {unit of measure} side" for real-world situations, not math, where unit of measure is an irrelevancy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cowper Kettle's suggestion of

> A square with a side with a length of 42

is fine, but since all the sides are of the same length, you can also say

> A square with **sides of** length 42 (centimeters).

or

> A square, 42 (centimeters) **on each side**.

or

> A square, 42 (centimeters) **per** side.

Side note (pun intended):  For rectangles, where you have to define the lengths of two sides, it would be common to say:

> A rectangle, 24 **by** 42 centimeters.

or written as:

> A 24**x**42 rectangle.

Here the "x" is the symbol for mathematical multiplication.  When spoken you would say, "24 *by* 42", as in the previous example.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply say "a 24-inch square".